# Rails db migration same timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, migration, timestamp

*I have like 173 migration files in <>/db/migrate.*

When I try to create a new migration, **the timestamp generated in the same as the previously generated migration**?

### How to manage this timestamp in rails 3 for migrations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, what we found out is that by mistake we added a migration with a timestamp on the future. We were testing parts of the app that depend on the date. Then all migrations generated after had the same timestamp + 1 at the end.